# Google Vision web entities returns score higher than 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I'm trying to find documentation on what is the highest score for web entities.

Some docs show that the range is from 0 to 1.
But the issue is that I see results that have score higher than 1...

For example if you use this image: https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.172866450.9713/ra,fitted_v_neck,x1950,dd2121:8219e99865,front-c,275,133,750,1000-bg,f8f8f8.u5.jpg

In https://cloud.google.com/vision/ drag & drop section you'll see in web entities section that T-shirt score is 1.9978.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Vision API always return a [value between 0 and 1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels#label_detection_responses). It's similar to confidence level in statistics or chance in probability; it's always between 0 and 1. 1 is already "certainty".

If you do somehow see a value bigger than 1, it's likely just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Google Vision API and the score was 0.97  < 1.

According to my experience, the score is always between 0 and 1.

Answer (score -1):

I assume it´s a bug in the online demo. I have never experienced this behavior in one of my cloud vision projects. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate) also specifies a score in the range [0,1].